How to prove the convergence of Gechberg-Saxton algorithm?
I just have a problem that Gerchberg-Saxton algortihm is no worse than the previous iteration
but not sure whether it is convergent.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
